# Variable is suddenly not defined, despite being defined

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a project with APIs, and just suddenly out of nowhere my code refuses to run. It states that:

> "NameError: name 'albumid' is not defined"

and I'm confused on how and why. I already directly stated the variable in a different function but it still wouldnt work.

I've tried directly calling the variable name in the function, and making it global across all functions, but to no avail.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import *
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
from io import BytesIO
import discogs_client
import requests
import json

d = discogs_client.Client(
    'MarbleSky/1.0',
    consumer_key='sCjBNcnSQyoyaAqasUMI',
    consumer_secret='VQxHMWAZyzuteAIZmzQSGVStNmCWSxEC'
)

root = Tk()
root.title = ("Code Lab II App")
root.geometry("500x980")
root.resizable(0,0)


#background image
bg = PhotoImage(file = "Main UI.png")

bglabel = Label(root, image=bg)
bglabel.place(x=0,y=0)



#first two entry boxes for the artist and song name(if desired).
artistInput = Entry(root, font=("Helvetica", 20))
artistInput.place(y=150,x=95)

albumInput = Entry(root, font=("Helvetica", 20))
albumInput.place(y=195,x=95)

def getName():
    global resultName
    try: 
        artist_name = artistInput.get()

        artist = d.search(artist_name, type="artist", sort='rating',sort_order='desc')
        
        if artist_name == "":
            artistname.config(text="Enter artist name.")

        elif artist and artist[0].name:
            resultName = artist[0].name.split(' (')[0]
            return resultName
        else:
            return (f"\"{artist_name}\" not found.")
    
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e} 2")
        return "N/A"


def getAlbum():
    global albumName
    global albumid
    try: 
        artist_name = resultName
        songname = albumInput.get()
        album = d.search(songname, artist=artist_name, type="master", sort='rating',sort_order='desc')

        if artist_name == "":
            return "Enter artist name."
            
        elif album and album[0]:
            albumName = album[0].title
            albumid = album[0].id
            print(albumName)
            return albumName
        elif album and album[1]:
            return (f"\"{album}\" not found.")
        else:
            return (f"\"{album}\" not found.")
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e} 2")
        return "N/A"
    
def getDetails():
        global albumid
        
        url = f"https://api.discogs.com/masters/{albumid}?&key=sCjBNcnSQyoyaAqasUMI&secret=VQxHMWAZyzuteAIZmzQSGVStNmCWSxEC"  
        response = requests.get(url)
        data = response.json()

        with open("Ex1.json",'w') as file:
            json.dump(data,file,indent =6)

        try:
            image_url = data['images'][0]['resource_url']
            x = requests.get(image_url)
            if x.status_code == 200:
                img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(BytesIO(x.content)))
                return img
            else:
                print(f"Failed to fetch image. Status code: {x.status_code}")
        except (KeyError, IndexError) as e:
            print(f"Error fetching image: {e}")



thumb = PhotoImage(file = "noimg.png")
thumb_label = Label(root, image=thumb)
thumb_label.place(x=115,y=250)


artistname = Label(root, text="Artist",
                    font="Helvetica",
                    fg='white',
                    bg='black',
                    anchor="center",
                    width=30)
artistname.place(y=560,x=65)

songname = Label(root, text="Album",
                  font=("Helvetica",15,"bold"),
                  fg="white",bg="black",
                  anchor="center",
                  width=40)
songname.place(y=530,x=5)

def updateText(e):
    name = getName()
    title = getAlbum()
    img = getDetails()
    artistname.config(text=name)
    songname.config(text=title)
    thumb_label.config(image=img)


root.bind('<Return>', updateText)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback. You probably want to have: `albumid = None` just below the imports.

Comment: `albumid` is defined *conditionally*: it doesn't get defined until `album` and `album[0]` are both true. `global albumid` does not *define* anything; it just says that any assignment to `albumid`, *if it exists*, should act on a global variable named `albumid` instead of a local variable.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, I will be using them in my code. As it turns out, the website my API is sourced from is down resulting in none of my variables taking any info.